# How do I associate my Web Apps account with my SOFU accounts?

Tags: support, openid, account-association

Since I manually associated my SO, SF, SU and MSO accounts months ago, Web Apps was my first experience with the automatic account association feature.  It's nice, but I have a small nitpick: it copied over the name/OpenID/Gravatar I used on MSO, which is different than the ones I use on SO/SF/SU.  As you have probably guessed by now, I wanted the SO/SF/SU name, OpenID and Gravatar.  (Interestingly, when my Area 51 account was created, it did get my SO/SF/SU info, not my MSO info.)  Is there a way to choose which account to use as the "primary" associated account, when an option is available?

(I wasn't sure whether to post this on Meta WebApps or Meta SO; it seems to apply equally to both.  My story, if one becomes necessary, is that I'm providing an outlet to test the migration functionality.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the "accounts" tab on [your user page on the webapps.stackexchange.com site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/256/popular-demand) (not on this one it's invalid on the meta.webapps site) and click on "Copy profile from ..." buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I must've been unclear; that is exactly what I did on the main site, and it worked.  But the changes didn't propagate to meta, and as you say, there's no option here.

Comment: Ah, OK, it's a bug then.

Comment: @Kinopiko, actually, it is fixed now.  My first thought was that some mod took pity on me and fixed it manually, but I doubt any mod would do that without leaving a comment.  So I conclude that there's just some propagation delay.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you sign up here with the same OpenID you use on SOFU, the accounts will be associated automatically. At least, that's what happened to me.

Comment: All of my SOFU accounts, my MSO account and my WebApps account use the same OpenID.  My SOFU and MSO accounts contain different information, though; the problem is that the "wrong" set of information was copied here automatically.